# Replace value in all but the last column

Tags: r

I have this section to replace value `99` in all columns to `NA`. But I don't want the column `respondent_id` to be effected.

```
SOURCE_SUBSET[SOURCE_SUBSET==99] <- NA
```

Comment: `i <- names(SOURCE_SUBSET) != "respondent_id"; SOURCE_SUBSET[SOURCE_SUBSET==99, i] <- NA`. Also, not my downvotes but what about a mcve? You are not new to SO...

Comment: It gives this error : Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, SOURCE_SUBSET == 9, i, value = NA) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(SOURCE_SUBSET)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(SOURCE_SUBSET, 20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols <- names(SOURCE_SUBSET)[which(!(names(SOURCE_SUBSET) %in% "respondent_id"))]

for(i in cols){
  SOURCE_SUBSET[SOURCE_SUBSET[, i] == 99, i] <- NA
}
```